# Linking multiple object files in c++ but no ouput

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am new to c++ programming and know the basics of c++. I am trying to link three files, but i am unable to get the output.I am studying the book c++ cookbook right now

Suppose we have the files a.hpp a.cpp, b.hpp b.cpp,c.hpp c.cpp with the following code:

**a.hpp**

```
#ifndef A_HPP_INCLUDED
#define A_HPP_INCLUDED
void a();
#endif
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>
void a()
{
    std::cout<<"a \n ";
}
```

**b.hpp**

```
#ifndef B_HPP_INCLUDED
#define B_HPP_INCLUDED
void b();
#endif
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.hpp"
#include <iostream>
void b()
{
    std::cout<<"b \n ";
}
```

**c.hpp**

```
#ifndef C_HPP_INCLUDED
#define C_HPP_INCLUDED
void c();
#endif
```

**c.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"
#include "c.hpp"
void c()
{
    a();
    b();

}

int main()
{
    c();
    return 0;
}
```

I have created all the files in one folder and commands i used to compile and link them are

```
$:g++ -c -Wall a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
$:g++ -o -Wall a.o b.o c.o
$:./a.out
```

I was expecting the outout

```
a
b
```

but there was no output at all.Request you all to help me out with this.

Comment: The first paragraph mentions `ab.h` and `ab.c`, but those are not used.  Are the build commands correct?  Ignoring those two files, it all looks correct and should work as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `-o` from your `g++` command line.

You are currently telling `g++` to link your objects together to a file called `-Wall`. So the alternative solution would be to call `./-Wall` instead of `./a.out`.

Due to the spaces in your strings (`" \n "` vs. `"\n"`), you'll still not be getting the exact expected output. Also you will probably want to replace:

```
std::cout << "something \n";
```

with

```
std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
```

if you want to have the data on screen immediately (flushing). See also [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Comment: Oddly enough, the top answers in the linked question contradict what you're stating...

Comment: Can you add a quote? From what I read, they do not contradict, at least the accepted one doesn't. It just says that if you want to flush your output, use `std::endl`. On command line output, I usually do that to avoid loss of (debugging) data in the case of a crash or anything.

Comment: It contradicts your claim that `endl` helps portability. That claim is spoiling an otherwise good answer.

Comment: Humm, I thought so. However, reading over the linked answer again showed me that I'm wrong, going to edit immediately.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thank you :) when i typed in ./-Wall I was able to get the output.But i actually used it so that the compiler can show warnings if there are any.Could you please let me know the correct usage of -Wall? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: `-Wall` is okay. But `-o` expects a file name as argument, so you'd want to type for example `g++ -Wall -o foo a.o b.o c.o` so that your executable is then called `foo`, runnable with `./foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$:g++ a.o b.o c.o -o your_output_program_name -Wall
```

try using this command. You will certainly get all things working correctly